# How to debug init segfault during boot in linux

Tags: android, linux-kernel, qemu

**Context**: Booting Android in an emulator (qemu) using a custom linux kernel.

At some point during the boot, dmesg shows:

**[...] init[1]: segfault at 14 ip 0000000000566abb sp 00007ffc181a8670 error 4 in init[400000+22e000]**

and then the kernel enters a bootloop with

**[...] init: Reboot ending, jumping to kernel**

**[...] reboot: Restarting system with command 'bootloader'**

**[...] reboot: machine restart**

So, I need some advice on how to debug this thing. How can I know what is causing that error in init?

Thank you!

Comment: Could something like this help: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Debugging_with_QEMU ?

Comment: Check what error code 4 means (I think it's a signal number, though I might be wrong) and check sources where it breaks.